# Why is the wave impedance calculated as $\eta = \eta_0 / \sqrt{\epsilon_r} = \dfrac{377}{\sqrt{4.0}} = 188.5 \ \Omega$?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electrical-resistance, maxwell-equations

I am currently studying the textbook *Microwave Engineering*, fourth edition, by David Pozar. Chapter **1.4 THE WAVE EQUATION AND BASIC PLANE WAVE SOLUTIONS** says the following:

> **Plane Waves in a Lossless Medium**
>
> In a lossless medium, $\epsilon$ and $\mu$ are real numbers, and so $k$ is real. A basic plane wave solution to the above wave equation can be found by considering an electric field with only an $\hat{x}$ component and uniform (no variation) in the $x$ and $y$ directions. Then, $\partial/\partial{x} = \partial/\partial{y} = 0$, and the Helmholtz equation of (1.42) reduces to
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2{E_x}}{\partial{z}^2} + k^2 E_x = 0. \tag{1.44}$$
> The two independent solutions to this equation are easily seen, by substitution, to be of the form
> $$E_x(z) = E^+e^{-jkz} + E^-e^{jkz}, \tag{1.45}$$
> where $E^+$ and $E^-$ are arbitrary amplitude constants.
> The above solution is for the time harmonic case at frequency $\omega$. In the time domain, this result is written as
> $$\mathcal{E}_x(z, t) = E^+ \cos(\omega t - kz) + E^- \cos(\omega t + kz), \tag{1.46}$$
> where we have assumed that $E^+$ and $E^-$ are real constants. Consider the first term in (1.46). This term represents a wave traveling in the $+z$ direction because, to maintain a fixed point on the wave $(\omega t - kz = \text{constant})$, one must move in the $+z$ direction as time increases. Similarly, the second term in (1.46) represents a wave traveling in the negative $z$ direction – hence the notation $E^+$ and $E^-$ for these wave amplitudes. The velocity of the wave in this sense is called the *phase velocity* because it is the velocity at which a fixed phase point on the wave travels, and it is given by
>
> $$v_p = \dfrac{dz}{dt} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\left( \dfrac{\omega t - \text{constant}}{k} \right) = \dfrac{\omega}{k} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\mu \epsilon}} \tag{1.47}$$
>
> In free-space, we have $v_p = 1/\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon_0} = c = 2.998 \times 10^8 \ \text{m}/\text{sec}$, which is the speed of light.
> The *wavelength*, $\lambda$, is defined as the distance between two successive maxima (or minima, or any other reference points) on the wave at a fixed instant of time. Thus,
> $$(\omega t - kz) - [\omega t - k(z + \lambda)] = 2\pi,$$
> so
> $$\lambda = \dfrac{2\pi}{k} = \dfrac{2 \pi v_p}{\omega} = \dfrac{v_p}{f} \tag{1.48}$$
>
> A complete specification of the plane wave electromagnetic field should include the magnetic field. In general, whenever $\bar{E}$ or $\bar{H}$ is known, the other field vector can be readily found by using one of Maxwell's curl equations. Thus, applying (1.41a) to the electric field of (1.45) gives $H_x = H_z = 0$, and
> $$H_y = \dfrac{j}{\omega \mu} \dfrac{\partial{E_x}}{\partial{z}} = \dfrac{1}{\eta}(E^+ e^{-jkz} - E^- e^{jkz}), \tag{1.49}$$
> where $\eta = \omega \mu / k = \sqrt{\mu/\epsilon}$ is known as the *intrinsic impedance* of the medium. The ratio of the $\bar{E}$ and $\bar{H}$ field components is seen to have units of impedance, known as the *wave impedance*; for planes waves the wave impedance is equal to the intrinsic impedance of the medium. In free-space the intrinsic impedance is $\eta_0 = \sqrt{\mu_0/\epsilon_0} = 377 \ \Omega$. Note that the $\bar{E}$ and $\bar{H}$ vectors are orthogonal to each other and orthogonal to the direction of propagation ($\pm \hat{z}$); this is a characteristic of transverse electromagnetic (TEM) waves.
>
> **EXAMPLE 1.1 BASIC PLANE WAVE PARAMETERS**
>
> A plane wave propagating in a lossless dielectric medium has an electric field given as $\mathcal{E}_x = E_0 \cos(\omega t - \beta z)$ with a frequency of $5.0 \ \text{GHz}$ and a wavelength in the material of $3.0 \ \text{cm}$. Determine the propagation constant, the phase velocity, the relative permittivity of the medium, and the wave impedance.
>
> *Solution*
> From (1.48) the propagation constant is $k = \dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda} = \dfrac{2\pi}{0.03} = 209.4 \ \text{m}^{-1}$, and from (1.47) the phase velocity is
> $$v_p = \dfrac{\omega}{k} = \dfrac{2\pi f}{k} = \lambda f = (0.03)(5 \times 10^9) = 1.5 \times 10^8 \ \text{m}/\text{sec}.$$
> This is slower than the speed of light by a factor of $2.0$. The relative permittivity of the medium can be found from (1.47) as
> $$\epsilon_r = \left( \dfrac{c}{v_p} \right)^2 = \left( \dfrac{3.0 \times 10^8}{1.5 \times 10^8} \right)^2 = 4.0$$
> The wave impedance is
> $$\eta = \eta_0 / \sqrt{\epsilon_r} = \dfrac{377}{\sqrt{4.0}} = 188.5 \ \Omega$$

I'm confused about this part:

> The wave impedance is
> $$\eta = \eta_0 / \sqrt{\epsilon_r} = \dfrac{377}{\sqrt{4.0}} = 188.5 \ \Omega$$

Note that the concept of *wave impedance* is introduced here:

> where $\eta = \omega \mu / k = \sqrt{\mu/\epsilon}$ is known as the *intrinsic impedance* of the medium. The ratio of the $\bar{E}$ and $\bar{H}$ field components is seen to have units of impedance, known as the *wave impedance*; for planes waves the wave impedance is equal to the intrinsic impedance of the medium. In free-space the intrinsic impedance is $\eta_0 = \sqrt{\mu_0/\epsilon_0} = 377 \ \Omega$. Note that the $\bar{E}$ and $\bar{H}$ vectors are orthogonal to each other and orthogonal to the direction of propagation ($\pm \hat{z}$); this is a characteristic of transverse electromagnetic (TEM) waves.

So it says that "for planes waves the wave impedance is equal to the intrinsic impedance of the medium." My first thought was to calculate the *intrinsic impedance* of the medium by using $\eta = \omega \mu / k = \sqrt{\mu/\epsilon}$. But we don't know what $\mu$ is, so it isn't clear how we could use this formula. Comparing this to the solution, the author has written that $\eta = \eta_0 / \sqrt{\epsilon_r} = \dfrac{377}{\sqrt{4.0}} = 188.5 \ \Omega$. But this formula is different from what's in the author's explanation/introduction, so it isn't clear to me what this is. Why is the *wave impedance* calculated as $\eta = \eta_0 / \sqrt{\epsilon_r} = \dfrac{377}{\sqrt{4.0}} = 188.5 \ \Omega$?

Comment: For many materials is reasonable to assume $\mu \approx \mu_0$.

Comment: @ThePhoton But here we have $\eta = \eta_0/\sqrt{\epsilon_r} = \dfrac{\sqrt{\mu_0/\epsilon_0}}{\sqrt{\epsilon_r}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\mu_0/\epsilon_0}{\epsilon_r}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r}}$, so how is $\mu \approx \mu_0$ relevant?

Comment: @ThePhoton I don't understand the point you're trying to make. Even if we accept that $\mu \approx \mu_0$, it is not sufficient to get $\eta = \eta_0 / \sqrt{\epsilon_r}$.

Comment: If $\mu=\mu_0$ then $\eta = \sqrt\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_r\epsilon_0}=\frac{\eta_0}{\sqrt\epsilon_r}$.

Comment: @ThePhoton But if we're only assuming that $\mu \approx \mu_0$, as you said, then where is the $\epsilon_0$ coming from? The point I'm making is that we start with the standard formula $\eta = \sqrt{\mu/\epsilon}$ (as given by the author), so what is the reasoning that then leads to $\eta = \eta_0 / \sqrt{\epsilon_r}$? [...]

Comment: [...] We can't start at the endpoint $\eta = \eta_0/\sqrt{\epsilon_r} = \dfrac{\sqrt{\mu_0/\epsilon_0}}{\sqrt{\epsilon_r}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\mu_0/\epsilon_0}{\epsilon_r}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r}}$ and then reason backwards, because then we're starting with the knowledge that we're trying to justify in the first place, and then using that knowledge to justify itself.

Comment: I didn't start at the endpoint. I started with the defintion of $\eta$, which is defined as $\sqrt\frac{\mu}{\epsilon}$. Then $\mu$ is defined as $\mu_r\mu_0$, but in this case $\mu_r=1$. And $\epsilon$ is defined as $\epsilon_r\epsilon_0$. And $\eta$ is defined as $\sqrt\frac{\mu}{\epsilon}$. From these definitions we get to the endpoint $\eta=\frac{\eta_0}{\sqrt{\epsilon_r}}$.

Comment: The assumption that $\mu_r=1$ isn't included in the text you quoted, but it is a common one if you aren't dealing with ferrite materials or nickel. Whether it's actually included in the book and you didn't notice it to quote it, or whether it was actually missing from the book, I don't know.

Comment: @ThePhoton Interesting. I had no idea about that – it has not been mentioned in the text thus far. Thanks for taking the time to clarify this. Feel free to post this as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In microwave engineering it's common to assume $\mu_r=1$, or equivalently $\mu=\mu_0$ for any material that isn't specifically known to be strongly magnetic, such as a ferrite material or nickel. I don't know whether Pozar actually forgot to mention this assumption, or if you just missed it in your reading, or it was in an early version of the book and got dropped by later edits, or what.

But with this assumption we have defined $\eta$ as

$$\eta = \sqrt\frac{\mu}{\epsilon}$$

then

$$\eta = \sqrt\frac{\mu_r\mu_0}{\epsilon_r\epsilon_0}$$

Since we assume $\mu_r=1$ we have

$$\eta = \sqrt\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_r\epsilon_0}$$

and from the definition $\eta_0=\sqrt\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}$,

$$\eta = \frac{\eta_0}{\sqrt{\epsilon_r}}.$$